# How to defer javascript files in theme.liquid in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

i have checked my website performance in https://gtmetrix.com/.And it says that i need to defer my javascript files. My theme.liquid file is like this:[image]

As you can see i have two js files at head section, when i am trying to put that files at the bottom after  tag my product page functionality not working, i have used jquery in script tag in my product page, in that scipt tag i am using also some liquid code. So what can i do , why product page functionality not working when i am puting jquery and slick-carousel at the bottom of my page (also i have tried to put defer keyword in jquery and slick-carousel script tags) sorry for my english. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the scripts from the `<head>` to the bottom of the page, before the `app.js`.
2. Move your inline scripts from the product page somewhere in between the jQuery script and the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

According to the second Vladimir's suggestion, I propose to wrap inline script from the product page in the condition:
{% if template contains 'product' %}
 ... inline script from product page
{% endif %}

This allow you to add inline script only on the product page.